# STM32L-Discovery error message?

Tags: stm32ldiscovery

I'm trying to program a stm32l-discovery board and have come across this error that keeps appearing when I try to build my project.

```
error: #29: expected an expression
       for (int i = 0; i <999; i++){
```

I'm using Keil uVision 4.

Source:

```
while (1) {
   ////fade up
   int i = 0; 
   for (int i = 0; i <999; i++) { 
      TIM_SetCompare2(TIM2,i);
      ////Pulse width is set with this function 
      delay(100);
      //// the '2' relates to the channel in use 
   }
}
```

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: It's better if you add that section of your code to your question, starting a few lines *before* that for.

Comment: while (1)
  {

    //fade up
  int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <999; i++)
  {

      TIM_SetCompare2(TIM2,i);                                         //Pulse width is set with this function
      delay(100);                                                      // the '2' relates to the channel in use
    }

Comment: Is the code i added to your question the same you are using?

Comment: ye its the same as that!

Comment: any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, the first issue is that you don't need to declare int i outside the for, remove that line.

Comment: ok but im still getting the same error message.

Comment: You get that error when your syntax is wrong, but the code above is valid c99 code...

Comment: @RonanSmith: You might not be using c99.  try:
`int i = 0; for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) { ... }`